# How to punctuate lists in general?

Tags: punctuation, writing, lists

(1) How to punctuate lists in general? (2) also, what case to use?

```
In the case study, signal comparison could be used for:
 • signals from redundant channels of emergency stop button,
 • output signals of redundant processing units,
 • feedback signals from frequency converter and contactor,
 • also result comparison of diagnostic techniques and measures, that have dependencies.
```

VS.

```
In the case study, signal comparison could be used for:
 • signals from redundant channels of emergency stop button;
 • output signals of redundant processing units;
 • feedback signals from frequency converter and contactor;
 • also result comparison of diagnostic techniques and measures, that have dependencies.
```

VS.

```
In the case study, signal comparison could be used for:
 • signals from redundant channels of emergency stop button
 • output signals of redundant processing units
 • feedback signals from frequency converter and contactor
 • also result comparison of diagnostic techniques and measures, that have dependencies
```

VS.

```
In the case study, signal comparison could be used for:
 • Signals from redundant channels of emergency stop button
 • Output signals of redundant processing units
 • Feedback signals from frequency converter and contactor
 • Also result comparison of diagnostic techniques and measures, that have dependencies
```

(3) is ":" necessary?

(4) is it (everything) the same for all cases?

Comment: There are several questions on this already. Use the search function in the top right and you'll find plenty of answers.

Comment: Can you please directly refer to these questions instead of "just search"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colon is not strictly necessary, and punctuation is not necessary at the ends of the bullets (unless they are examples of sentences, as we sometimes see on English.SE).

If this is for a legal, technical, or academic paper or publication, however, you should consult the style guide for whichever organization's rules govern the writing of prose. Short of that, for informal contexts bullets are understood to be their own type of punctuation.

Note also that your last bulleted phrase doesn't even require a comma:

> Also result comparison of diagnostic techniques and measures, that have dependencies

works better as

> Also result comparison of diagnostic techniques and measures that have dependencies

and still better without the leading conjunction

> Result comparison of diagnostic techniques and measures that have dependencies

Finally, it is not even necessary to capitalize each bullet's first word unless it represents a complete sentence said in context or is a proper noun.

In short, bulleted lists don't have to behave like the lists you encounter in sentences. Most ordinary rules you know are optional.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use style 2; it is certainly preferred in English legal writing.

However, you have a mistake in style 2 - the conjunction between the penultimate and last item should be on the same line as the penultimate item, after the semi-colon.