# Comma in a sentence just before the start of a list

Tags: commas, questions, lists

If I am asking a complex question, I would write it like this:

> Do you have, by chance, three
>   pennies on you?

Should I write a complex question that turns into a list without the comma?

> Do you have, by chance:
>
> - 3 pennies?
> - 2 shillings?

or like this

> Do you have, by chance,:
>
> - 3 pennies?
> - 2 shillings?

Comment: Related, but probably not a strict dupe: [How to punctuate lists in general?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10876/how-to-punctuate-lists-in-general) and [How should lists of questions be punctuated?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/how-should-lists-of-questions-be-punctuated)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a [complex question](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/complqueterm.htm) is something different from the sense I think you mean it here.

> **complex question** A fallacy in which the answer to a given question presupposes a prior answer to a prior question.

Second, in a list following a parenthetical expression, you are entitled to precede the list with a comma.

> Do you have, by chance, three pennies on you?

It is not necessary to add bullet points or use a colon or whatever. You can make lists with this, but they are not necessarily better than your first instinct.

Comment: Would it be more "complex sentence as a question"?

Answer (score 0):

You never need a comma and a colon back to back.

> Do you have, by chance:
>
> 3 pennies?
>
> 2 shillings?

Seems like the way to go, to me.

Answer (score 0):

Of the two, choose the first one: a colon without a comma. A list of items is a distinct construction with its own rules, so you don't need to replicate the structure of a conventional sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not, and the reason is simple:

When you start a list you use only the **colon**, and since you can't (except in *other* few cases) use two punctuation signs next to each other, the comma disappears.

Comment: You can't use two punctuations signs next to each other!? Oh, no!!

Comment: @phenry: What's wrong? If you have something interesting to say, say it. Otherwise, restrain yourself from commenting.

Comment: @Alenanno: It was just a joke. I'm sorry if you didn't find it amusing. Try being less thin-skinned.

Comment: @phenry: It didn't sound friendly at all, try making better jokes next time. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: I am gratified to see that at least one other person disagrees with you.

Comment: @phenry: Maybe that user was being sarcastic as well, and therefore disagreeing with you too, how can you be sure of that?